# Programmatically Enable Smart Tag in Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook, smart-tags

There's a "global" checkbox titled "label text with smart tags" in Outlook that enables/disables the entire list of smart tag recognizers, under Tools/Options/Mail Format/Editor Options/Proofing/AutoCorrect Options/Smart Tags. I can programmatically enable the individual recognizers in the list, but the million dollar question is, how to programmatically enable/disable the "global" checkbox.  I checked the registry and group policy to no avail.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

John.

Answer (score 2):

If the value should be stored in registry, I'd do the following: Unfortunately (or fortunately? ;-)) I don't have Outlook 2007, so I can't test it on my own, but I'd suggest using [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) from the SysInternals suite to see which registry value is changed when you check/save that global option. This way you might find the proper value to change.

Comment: Seems like a great tool!  I'll give it a spin and see where things get changed.  Thanks!

Comment: Filemon as well as some of the outlook extentions used files!